# perl module - how to reference files included in the Manifest

Tags: perl, module, package

I've created a module which has several extra files included, these are in the Manifest and are installed when I run 'make install', along with `MyModule.pm`

My issue is how to reference these from the `MyModule`?

```
my $mfile = "incfile1.txt';  # this fails , as does ./  /  etc
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends where those files are installed.

If they are always installed in the same place relative to the module's .pm files, then you need only determine the install directory of the module. One way of doing so is to read the %INC value for the .pm file, which is the path to the included module, and process that value into the path to your file.

So let's pretend that your module is installed at /usr/lib/perl5/5.18.0/MyModule, and the extra files in the same directory. One way to do it is:

```
my $mypath = $INC{'MyModule/Work.pm'};
my $mypath =~ s/Work\.pm/OtherFile.txt/;
open(my $fh, "<", $mypath);
```